# How to customize the vertical spacing between an org-mode heading and its content in the folded view?

Tags: org-mode, formatting, line-spacing

**Subtree View:**

```
* Header 1

** Header 2
```

**Children View:**

```
* Header 1

** Header 2
```

**Desired Children View:**

```
* Header 1
** Header 2
```

Is there a way to treat the blank line between Header 1 and Header 2 semantically as formatting information rather than as a blank line of "empty content"?

More generally, it would be helpful to provide an option that allows blank lines at the beginning and end of a content section located directly under a heading to be suppressed when locally expanding that heading from the folded view (3 dots) to the children view (through a single TAB keystroke), since this is still supposed to be a compacted view of the file, and only show all of these formatting lines when one enters the full subtree view by hitting TAB a second time.

Comment: I can't replicate the behaviour that you are describing as the current state. Could you please clarify?
When I do 
`* heading 1 [new line x2] ** heading 2`

and then fold it, I get

`* heading 1...`

Is this question specific to cycling of folding when done with `S-TAB`?

Comment: I've edited the original question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question to be clearer. Could you let me know if my answer regarding `org-cycle-separator-lines` is what you are looking for? 

It seems like you might be looking to either set the value for the variable to `0` to ignore the content of the empty lines, or `-N` to make empty lines appear in folded view regardless of location.

Answer (score 0):

You had mentioned that the behaviour you would like to see is similar to how `org-cycle-separator-lines` works, except that the variable only works at the end of a section (which I presume means that this does not do what you are looking for, since you would like it at the beginning/before a header).

`org-cycle-separator-lines` actually has a condition that can edit this behaviour that may allow what you are looking for. From the doc page:

```
org-cycle-separator-lines

Number of empty lines needed to keep an empty line between collapsed trees.

If you leave an empty line between the end of a subtree and the following
headline, this empty line is hidden when the subtree is folded.
[...]
If the number is negative, and the number of empty lines is at least -N,
all empty lines are shown.
```

So if you customize `org-cycle-separator-lines` to be for a negative number, you can get separator lines regardless of where they appear. I set this to `-1` and I have this behaviour:

Unfolded:

```
* heading 1


content


** heading 2
content

content

*** heading 3
some content 

** heading 2 2
```

Folded:

```
* heading 1


** heading 2

*** heading 3 

** heading 2 2
```

If you want no separator lines, change this value to `0`.

Comment: `org-cycle-separator-lines` cannot remove a blank line between a heading and the content directly underneath it because apparently org syntax specification considers that blank line as part of the content.  I include these blank lines because I want to see them in the fully expanded SUBTREE view, but in the more compact CHILDREN view I would like to be able to suppress any blank lines between the heading and the content directly underneath it just like `org-cycle-separator-lines` is able to do for any blank lines between the end of a content section and the next heading underneath it.

Comment: Also note that in the edited version of my original question, changing the value of `org-cycle-separator-lines` from `1` to `0` or `-1` has no effect on the desired result, i.e. suppressing the blank lines both at the beginning and at the end of the content section.